# How do I automatically trigger email notification with custom message after deployment (in CD pipeline) in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a CD pipeline with Azure Deploy task and I want to trigger a email notification to developers after successful deployment but with custom message. I researched on 'Send Email' task but it requires an SMTP server (say google SMTP). is there a feature within VSTS to trigger a mail?

Comment: A simple @oultook.com address is enough to use the Office365 email infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [SendGrid Email extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.sendgrid-email). You would need a SendGrip API key (hence a SendGrid account) but you can create one for free on [Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-en/marketplace/apps/SendGrid.SendGrid?tab=PlansAndPrice).

It would be limited to 25000  emails per month, but it should be enough. And if it isn't, you can upgrade your plan in no time

I Hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the [Send Email task developed by DutchWorkz B.V.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.SendEmail).

You can use the [Send Email task developed by Rene van Osnabrugge (Xpirit)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) which just need to specify the email addressed, subject and email body.

[image]